# How can i change camera position to move like hover?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hover or flying or better word to describe floating.
In the script now i'm just changing the camera position from place to place.
But instead i want the camera to float/hover to the next position and including terrain height changes. So it will float smooth. Maybe i should use raycast ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Camera firstCam;
    public Camera camera;
    public bool loop;
    public bool changeDirection;
    public bool lightningBallEffect;
    public bool lookAtTarget;

    private List<GameObject> TeleportBooths;

    TeleportationsCore[] tCores;
    private int boothIndex = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        InstantiateObjects gos = GetComponent<InstantiateObjects>();

        TeleportBooths = new List<GameObject>();
        TeleportBooths = gos.PrefabsList();
        firstCam.enabled = false;
        mainCamera.enabled = false;
        camera.enabled = true;

        tCores = TeleportBooths.Select(booth => booth.AddComponent<TeleportationsCore>()).ToArray();

        WorkingBooth();
    }

    private void WorkingBooth()
    {
        if (tCores[boothIndex].NextWorkingBooth() == true)
            boothIndex++;
        if (boothIndex == tCores.Length)
            boothIndex = 0;
        player.transform.position = TeleportBooths[boothIndex].transform.position;
camera.transform.position = new Vector3(TeleportBooths[boothIndex].transform.position.x - 15, TeleportBooths[boothIndex].transform.position.y + 15, TeleportBooths[boothIndex].transform.position.z);
camera.transform.LookAt(TeleportBooths[boothIndex].transform);

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        WorkingBooth();
    }
}
```

This is what i tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFly : MonoBehaviour {

    public Camera camera;

    private Vector3 currentPos;
    private Vector3 targetPos;
    public float desiredCameraHeight;

    int movementspeed = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        //Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position);

        Ray ray = camera.ViewportPointToRay(Terrain.activeTerrain.transform.position);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            float cameraHeight = desiredCameraHeight - hit.distance;
            targetPos.y = cameraHeight;
            transform.position += Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, targetPos, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

But either using ScreenPointToRay or ViewportPointToRay the camera is not moving at all.

Comment: This will move the camera but now i need to find how to make the camera change it's height depending on the terrain areas if it's higher move the camera high then move it down lower. I want to keep the camera just a bit above the ground. At height 0.6 this is how just to make the camera move: transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementspeed; But how you calculate the height on the terrain and changing the camera height depending on it ?

Comment: I can help with this. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lerp method to move camera from position A to B smoothly. But to cater the varrying terrain height, You have to cast ray towards the ground and use the ray hit distance to set y value of the target position.

Here is a psuedocode:

```
//currentPos;
//targetPos;
//desiredCameraHeight;
//Racast down from camera to ground/terrain;
//cameraHeight = desiredCameraHeight - hitDistance;
//targetPos.y = cameraHeight;
//Lerp(currentPos,targetPos);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried something updated my question with what i tried. Could you please look at it ? Thanks.